# How do I check the current boot parameter list in Linux?

Tags: linux, boot, grub

During test, I sometimes add/change boot parameters to */boot/grub/menu.lst* (suse), or at the grub screen during boot.

How do I check what boot parameters have been used after the system is done booting?

Comment: check this http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/10-boot-time-parameters-you-should-know-about-the-linux-kernel.html it may be helpfull

Comment: The "kernel command line" which contains those "boot parameters" should be in the system log, accessible with the `dmesg` command.  A copy of the kernel command line is also in /proc/cmdline.

Comment: @sawdust, cat /proc/cmdline did the trick.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The bootloader (grub in this case) will pass the *boot parameters* to the Linux kernel in a memory buffer called the *kernel command line*.  The *kernel command line*, along with other console messages output during boot, should be in the system log, retrievable with the `dmesg` command.

A copy of the *kernel command line* is also in the file `/proc/cmdline`.

Answer (score 0):

If your boot type is EFI,
you can just type in cli after Linux booted:

```
efibootmgr -v
```

to see the current boot options and which partition/device you booted from.

Look at `man efibootmgr` if you are curious.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).